# conditional cast from [Message] to [Message] always succeeds

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, message

```
if let context = delegate?.managedObjectContext {


        do {

      let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Message>(entityName: "Message")

          let messages = try(context.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [Message])
```

> This gives me the error "conditional cast from [Message] to [Message] always succeeds"

```
            for message in messages! {
                context.delete(message)

            }
            try(context.save())

        } catch let err {
            print (err)
        }
```

> Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: remove the `as? [Message]` part as it seems not mandatory in this context, because the returned value has already been casted as `[Message]` and no need explicit cast from you.

Answer (score 4):

Prior to swift 3, `context.fetch()` only returned an `[AnyObject]`. That was why you had to cast it like that.

But now in Swift 3, the `NSFetchRequest` class becomes generic and `context.fetch()` will return an array of the generic type you specified when creating the fetch request. It's much more type safe now.

Therefore, you don't need to cast it to the type you want anymore, because it already *is* that type!

```
let messages = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
```